# using whois with Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, whois

I am trying to use the external library of [whois](https://pypi.org/project/whois/) but i am getting the error `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` I have included the package in my settings file. Here is the code for views:

```
class PreviousSearchView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            searchdomain = request.POST['searchdomain']
            domain = whois.query(searchdomain)           ##### Error on this line
            date = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(domain)
            search = Search(
                searchdomain = searchdomain,
                date = date,
                user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
            )
            search.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

Comment: it seems many peoples have the same problem. according to its [github_issue_page](http://github.com/DannyCork/python-whois/issues)

Answer (score 0):

The [whois](https://pypi.org/project/whois/) package is for linux if you are using windows try [python-whois](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/).